# How can i get Text from a view, not a Textview

Tags: java, android, view, textview, accessibilityservice

i worked with AccessibilityService,everything is ok.

i want get text from screen, but it's a view, not TextView.
someone tell me how to.

it show view with Monitor, but show text too.

AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeRoot = this.getRootInActiveWindow();

List nodeInfoList = nodeRoot.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("com.tencent.mm:id/oz");

AccessibilityNodeInfo info = nodeInfoList.get(1);

Log.d(TAG, info.getText());

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EConI.png)

Comment: post  some code plz!

Answer (score 0):

you how set text for this View?
when settext for view: You can set a tag for this view and save this tag and its value in hashmap(key is tag) and retrieve it when needed by tag.

Comment: the app is Wechat from tencent. i dont know they how to set text.  but i want to get it.